# How to not give the link in @username when someone mention and they're together?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

It will give the link if someone post @usernameone. But the problem is it still gives the link when they post something like this @usernameone@usernametwo. I don't know how to modify this code to make it works.

```
function mention($text) {
$patterns = array('@(http?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})/');
$replace = array('<a href="$1">$1</a>', '<a href="../../profile/$1">@$1</a>');
$result = preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $text);
return $result;
}
```

Call the function

```
<?php  echo mention($rowcom->description);?>
```

**Result**
[image: result]

**Expected Result**
[image: expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with this code, you just need to add a space at the end of the second element in `$replace` array :

```
function mention($text) {
    $patterns = array('@(http?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})/');
    $replace = array('<a href="$1">$1</a>', '<a href="../../profile/$1">@$1</a> ');
    $result = preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $text);

    return $result;
}

echo mention('@usernameone bla bla') . '<br>';
echo mention('@usernameone@usernametwo bla bla');
```

**OUTPUT**

[@usernameone](http://#) bla bla

[@usernameone](http://#) [@usernametwo](http://#) bla bla

**UPDATE**

If you want to exclude "stuck" usernames, your regex will become quite more complex :

```
$patterns = array('@(http?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '/(^|[\s\.,;\?\!])@(?![A-Za-z0-9_]+@)([A-Za-z0-9_@]+)/');
$replace = array('<a href="$1">$1</a>', '$1<a href="../../profile/$2">@$2</a> ');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.. but I wanna inactive the link if it's together because in my database it will not save if there's no space between them.

Comment: @mikha I edited the answer accordingly and added all the common punctuation that can precede a username. Don't forget to change the `$replace` line with `$2` instead of `$1` for the second replacement pattern.

Comment: it works but unfortunately if I post like this : `that's all @userone @usertwo` and the result becomes : `that's all@userone @usertwo` . How to fix it?

Comment: @mikha Just remove the space at the end : `@$2</a> ');` => `@$2</a>');`

Comment: still same, there's no effect

Comment: @mikha Yes you're true, I edited the **UPDATE** part, now it does work.

Comment: Yes, It works perfectly..  Thank you so much for helping me. Have a nice day.